# How to remove anti aliasing in render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, denoise, antialiasing

i am rendering out this image and I have anti-aliasing along my edges.

My noise threshold and min samples are set to 0, and my pixel filter is set to 1.5 on gaussian. Is there a way to blur these edges in order to remove the sharp pixelation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello ! This looks like it's already anti-aliased. Maybe you want to render in a higher resolution instead ?